# Get number of messages on TIBCO EMS(with SSL implemented and having connection factories) queue from TIBCO BW

Tags: tibco, ems

I wanted to know the number of messages on an EMS queue. With below

TibjmsAdmin admin = new TibjmsAdmin(in_var_server,in_var_username,in_var_password);

QueueInfo info = admin.getQueue(in_var_queue);

out_var_1 = info.getPendingMessageCount();

admin.close();

I was able to get the count from local EMS Server with no ssl connection.

Is there a way to get the same with EMS connections where SSL implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use JNDI to make any connection to EMS (this is highly recommended). When you create the JNDI connection you are allowed to create the environment and pass the SSL credential, then you can use your code.

There is a nice amount of example code locate at [your_tibco_instalation_directory]\ems\8.0\samples\java\JNDI

Here is how:

```
serverUrl = "ssl://localhost:7243";
// set SSL vendor
if (ssl_vendor != null && ssl_identity != null && ssl_password != null){
     environment.put(com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.VENDOR, ssl_vendor);
     environment.put(com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.IDENTITY, ssl_identity);
     environment.put(com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSSL.PASSWORD, ssl_password);
}
ConnectionFactory factory = new com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory(serverUrl,null,environment);
```

for more information see: tibjmsSSL.java on the Sample directory.